Excluding simultaneously properties of different JSON structures without Classes, using Jackson in Java
I'm working in this utility:
https://github.com/joseluisbz/Json-Modifier/blob/ec747830626b42d15eaa1e868fd6cc64f3be861e/SelfConsumed/src/main/java/self/consumed/ms/util/JsonMapperUtil.java#L46C26-L46C43
I would like to know if there are alternative to exclude properties of some JSON without classes of those JSON.
I designed this way:
// Method to initiate to exclude the paths inside of JSON
public static String pathsJsonExcluder(String jsonInput, List<String> listExcluded) throws IOException {
    JsonNode jsonNodeInput = getMapper().readTree(jsonInput);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    ExcluderDTO excluderDTO = ExcluderDTO
            .builder()
            .generator(getMapper().getFactory().createGenerator(stringWriter))
            .pathDeque(new ArrayDeque<>())
            .isRootObject(jsonNodeInput.isObject())
            .isRootArray(jsonNodeInput.isArray())
            .excludedProperties(listExcluded)
            .build();

    if (excluderDTO.isRootObject) {
        excluderDTO.generator.writeStartObject();
    }
    if (excluderDTO.isRootArray) {
        excluderDTO.generator.writeStartArray();
    }

    traverse(excluderDTO, jsonNodeInput, "", excluderDTO.isRootArray);

    excluderDTO.generator.flush();

    JsonNode jsonNodeOutput = getMapper().readTree(stringWriter.toString());
    return getMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonNodeOutput);
}

// method to traverse the JSON
private static void traverse(ExcluderDTO excluderDTO, JsonNode currentJsonNode, String currentFieldName, 
                             boolean previousIsArray) throws IOException {
    final String PATH_SEPARATOR = "/";
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>(excluderDTO.pathDeque);
    Collections.reverse(paths);
    String currentPath = PATH_SEPARATOR + String.join(PATH_SEPARATOR, paths);
    if (excluderDTO.excludedProperties.contains(currentPath)) {
        return;
    }
    if (currentJsonNode.isObject() && previousIsArray) {
        excluderDTO.generator.writeStartObject();
        isObject(excluderDTO, currentJsonNode);
    } else if (currentJsonNode.isObject() && !previousIsArray) {
        if (!currentFieldName.isEmpty()) {
            excluderDTO.generator.writeFieldName(currentFieldName);
            excluderDTO.generator.writeStartObject();
        }
        isObject(excluderDTO, currentJsonNode);
    } else if (currentJsonNode.isArray()) {
        if (excluderDTO.isRootObject || excluderDTO.isRootArray && !currentPath.equals(PATH_SEPARATOR)) {
            excluderDTO.generator.writeFieldName(currentFieldName);
            excluderDTO.generator.writeStartArray();
        }
        ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) currentJsonNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
            excluderDTO.pathDeque.push(String.valueOf(i));
            JsonNode arrayElement = arrayNode.get(i);
            traverse(excluderDTO, arrayElement, String.valueOf(i), true);
            excluderDTO.pathDeque.pop();
        }
        excluderDTO.generator.writeEndArray();
    } else {
        excluderDTO.generator.writeObjectField(currentFieldName, currentJsonNode);
    }
}

private static void isObject(ExcluderDTO excluderDTO, JsonNode currentJsonNode) throws IOException {
    Iterator<String> fieldNames = currentJsonNode.fieldNames();
    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
        String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
        excluderDTO.pathDeque.push(fieldName);
        JsonNode fieldValue = currentJsonNode.get(fieldName);
        traverse(excluderDTO, fieldValue, fieldName, false);
        excluderDTO.pathDeque.pop();
    }
    excluderDTO.generator.writeEndObject();
}

// DTO to pass properties
@Data
@Builder
private static class ExcluderDTO {
    private JsonGenerator generator;
    private Deque<String> pathDeque;
    private boolean isRootObject;
    private boolean isRootArray;
    private List<String> excludedProperties;
}

How to use it?
        String jsonInput = "{\"fecha\":\"2024-09-16T20:12:35.1034441\",\"dato\":{\"entero\":5,\"actions\":[{\"code\":\"1\",\"description\":\"one\"},{\"code\":\"2\",\"description\":\"two\"}]}}";
        System.out.println("jsonInput:" + System.lineSeparator() + jsonInput);
        List<String> listExcluded = List.of("/dato/entero", "/dato/actions/0");
        String jsonOutput = pathsJsonExcluder(jsonInput, listExcluded);
        System.out.println("jsonOutput:" + System.lineSeparator() + jsonOutput);

        jsonInput = "[{\"nombre\": \"John\", \"edad\": 30, \"direccion\": {\"calle\": \"Primera\",\"ciudad\": \"BAQ\"}}, {\"nombre\": \"Peter\", \"edad\": 25, \"direccion\": {\"calle\": \"Sexta\",\"ciudad\": \"BOG\"}}, {\"nombre\": \"Pepe\", \"edad\": 15, \"direccion\": {\"calle\": \"Decima\",\"ciudad\": \"CLO\"}}]";
        System.out.println("jsonInput:" + System.lineSeparator() + jsonInput);
        listExcluded = List.of("/1", "/0/direccion", "/2/direccion/calle");
        jsonOutput = pathsJsonExcluder(jsonInput, listExcluded);
        System.out.println("jsonOutput:" + System.lineSeparator() + jsonOutput);

The Output:
jsonInput:
{"fecha":"2024-09-16T20:12:35.1034441","dato":{"entero":5,"actions":[{"code":"1","description":"one"},{"code":"2","description":"two"}]}}
jsonOutput:
{"fecha":"2024-09-16T20:12:35.1034441","dato":{"actions":[{"code":"2","description":"two"}]}}
jsonInput:
[{"nombre": "John", "edad": 30, "direccion": {"calle": "Primera","ciudad": "BAQ"}}, {"nombre": "Peter", "edad": 25, "direccion": {"calle": "Sexta","ciudad": "BOG"}}, {"nombre": "Pepe", "edad": 15, "direccion": {"calle": "Decima","ciudad": "CLO"}}]
jsonOutput:
[{"nombre":"John","edad":30},{"nombre":"Pepe","edad":15,"direccion":{"ciudad":"CLO"}}]

As you see, there aren't classes and the previous code could be used in any JSON, because is not tied to particular JSON structure.
Is there alternative and easy way to do this (exclude simultaneously multiple properties from different JSON's without having the classes or modifying them)?
